# qt creator to give control from one window to another

Tags: qt

how to give control from one window to another by a pushbutton click

Answer (score 0):

Both windows must be part of the same application. Connect the `QPushButton` `clicked` signal to a slot on the other window in which `activateWindow()` is called.

Comment: dear baysmith i have a doubt i used qtcreator 2.0.1.....i have two windows mainwindow and childwindow.i want to display the second chilwindow when the push button of the mainwindowform pressed...can u help me...i am new to this qt....thanks alot for ur previous reply